# macos brew system: R packages fail to install with emutls_w

Tags: r, package

on a current macos system with the latest brew system (for gcc and other utilities), important packages like `lmtest` no longer install.

the error says the emutls_w library is not found.

Answer follows.

Answer (score 9):

the problem is that the current brew system seems to still use an older gcc version, that refers to itself as `aarch64-apple-darwin21/` (maybe only when installed earlier).  the R packages want what is relevant to the current version of macos, which is `aarch64-apple-darwin22` (see `uname -a`).

a nasty workaround is to

```
$ sudo bash
# pushd /opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc/
# ln -s aarch64-apple-darwin21 aarch64-apple-darwin22
```

then install what you need (in another terminal), and then

```
# rm aarch64-apple-darwin22
```

one could also try a `brew reinstall gcc` first.

Comment: for me the reinstallation of gcc worked!