# how do I change clang to gcc in R regarding MacOs?

Tags: r, gcc

After I change clang to gcc in terminal and when I type 'gcc --version' it returns 'gcc-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0' like I want. However when I check the complier in R or Rstudio using 'system("gcc --version")' it still returns 'Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)'.

Let me give me more background information since I'm new to MacOs. I was trying to install package [BiProbitPartial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiProbitPartial/index.html) onto R yet uinfortunately it's removed from CRAN hence I use 'install_url()' from library 'devtools' instead to install the package but get error information like 'library emutls_w not found' as in [macos brew system: R packages fail to install with emutls_w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096681/macos-brew-system-r-packages-fail-to-install-with-emutls-w) after whcih I try to subsititute gcc for clang.

Comment: update: I tried to install the package again under that circumstance and surprisingly it proceeded with many warnings but no errors and the package can be imported! Like I did many things wrong but it turns out just fine... I can continue my work but it still confuses me a lot.